# extjs overriding functions in action classes

Tags: extjs, overriding, action

How can I override the below action definition in custom javascript file?

```
Ext.define("my.action.form.DataAction", {
   extend: "my.action.Action",
   requires: ["my.action.Action"],
   alias: "action.dataaction",
   notifyActionSuccess: function(component, msgTemplate, model) {

      console.log("original action action");

   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ext.override(my.action.form.DataAction, {
    notifyActionSuccess: function(component, msgTemplate, model) {

      console.log("a new overridden action action");

   }
});
```

or you can use Ext.define:

```
Ext.define("my.action.form.DataActionOvrRide", {
    override: "my.action.form.DataAction",
    notifyActionSuccess: function(component, msgTemplate, model) {

        console.log("new overridden action action");

    }
});
```

Comment: if I have some other functions inside my.action.form.DataAction like notifyActionFailure, they wont get affect right?

Comment: Also if I execute this code in the chrome developer tool, will it work when my application was loaded?